# I didn't get all the data in Angular Form

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray, formgroups

I'm getting the questions from the database. I have created and submitted the form controls but no matter what I do, only the last value comes. I never got all the answers. I need to collect them and send them to the backend. Where is my fault?

```
anamnezQuestion: any;
  anamnezForm: FormGroup;
  answersDetail: any = [];

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAnamnezQuestion();

    this.anamnezForm = this.fb.group({
      answers: this.fb.array([this.newAnswers()]),
    });
  }

  answers(): FormArray {
    return this.anamnezForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
  }

  newAnswers(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      answerValue: new FormControl(''),
      answer: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  get anamnezFormGroup() {
    return (<FormArray>this.anamnezForm.get('answers')) as FormArray;
  }

  onFormSubmit(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(this.anamnezForm);
    console.log(this.anamnezFormGroup);
    console.log(this.answersDetail);
  }

  getAnamnezQuestion() {
    this.clientService.getAnamnezQuestion().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.anamnezQuestion = res.data;
    });
  }





<form [formGroup]="anamnezForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(anamnezForm.value)">
  <div formArrayName="answers">
    <div *ngFor="let questions of anamnezQuestion; let i = index">
      <div>{{ questions.id }}. {{ questions.question }}</div>

      <div
        *ngFor="let item of anamnezFormGroup.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
                formControlName="answerValue"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            aria-label="Text input with checkbox"
            formControlName="answer"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Gönder</button>
</form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjizl.png)

I want to enclose the results in an array. For example:

```
 answers:
 0:questionId:1 {checkBoxValue,InputValue} < Answer Value
 1:questionId:2 {checkBoxValue,InputValue} < Answer Value
 2:questionId:3 {checkBoxValue,InputValue} < Answer Value
```

or

```
question1:
0:{checkBoxValue,InputValue} < Answer Value
question2:
0:{checkBoxValue,InputValue} < Answer Value
question3:
0:{checkBoxValue,InputValue} < Answer Value
```

something like this

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqavz.png)

Comment: Images of code are better than nothing, but please use snippets instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you. I'm new here and trying to learn.

Comment: Hello, @Tolga. Yes it correct because you added only 1 `FormGroup` to the `answers: FormArray`. It's in the `ngOnInit` method in your code. To have `FormGroup`s for all questions/answers, you have to add/push `FromGroup` into your `FormArray` for each question in the `this.anamnezQuestion` array. Hope this is clear and helpful.

Comment: Hi alexJS, I understand what you mean actually. But how can I do?

Comment: You have to loop through the `this.anamnezQuestion` array when you get a data there in the `.subscribe((res: any) => { ... });` and for each item of this array add a `FormGroup` into the `FormArray`, like `this.answers().push(this.newAnswers());` and not add this `this.newAnswers()` into the `FormArray` on init, just create `FA` there - `this.anamnezForm = this.fb.group({answers: this.fb.array([])});`. So, you'll have the same amount of questions and answers `FormGroup`s and could get one that you need by `index`. Also, in the template you'll not need `*ngFor` through `FA`.

Comment: If still my comment-answer is not completely clear, please let me know, and I'll left an answer with refactoring of your code. In comments not enough space and available symbols to write full and clear answer)))

Comment: I did as you said and it worked. I've attached my edited changes as a photo below my main post. (working)

Thank you for your help AlexJs. Thank you so much.

Comment: @alexJS, it's better loop over FormArray.controls than over this.anamezQuestion. This avoid that if not correspondence in time the two arrays

Comment: @TolgaHATİPOĞLU I'm happy to help. I would very appreciate if you can vote for my comment that helped you(Click on arrow up behind the comment). Thanks and good luck 

Comment: Hello, @Eliseo. In the template agree with you, for sure. I noticed that `.html` file should be changed as well but didn't have enough symbols in the comment area to write it. In my comment I told about thast you have to loop over `this.anamnezQuestion` in the `.ts` file to create this `FormArray` by received data.

Comment: You don't have icons like  and  before each comment? Maybe it's because you are newcomer on SO. ‍♂️

Comment: @AlexJs, I'd love to upvote, but I don't see the arrows in the comments. When I press the arrow sign in the answers, the following warning appears.

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: @TolgaHATİPOĞLU, ok no problem. My pleasure to help not for achieves. I'm glad that my approach was helpful. Have a nice day)

Answer (score 0):

Only use a *ngFor: As you has a Form Array, use the *ngFor over "anamnezFormGroup.controls". Then use `anamnezQuestion[i]` to get the element of anamezQuestion.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of anamnezFormGroup.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i">

   <div>{{ anamnezQuestion[i].id }}. {{ anamnezQuestion[i].question }}</div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ... formControlName="answerValue">
      <input type="text" ... formControlName="answer">
   </div>
</div>
```